# How to use GEOS/C++ to efficiently find all point pairs closer than a threshold?

Tags: c++, geos

Can anyone tell me how to use GEOS/C++ to efficiently find all point pairs in a dataset closer than a threshold distance d?

I suspect this might involve quadtrees or rtrees but not quite sure how to query them.

Comment: What algorithms have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, got this working - and feel like putting the long answer here, as it has a lot of useful GEOS example bits in it.  Here we go.

Warnings

- I haven't compiled this - I stripped out a load of project specific stuff and replaced it with a simple Point class which probably needs a copy/assignment operator.  But it worked before I did that.
- I'm not sure this counts as clustering, as a long line of points each pair of which is closer than `tolerance` would count as a cluster (fine for my purposes).  Complexity is `O(n log n)` as long as your clusters don't get too big, I think.
  `tolerance` is defined as a square around each point, not a circle
- It uses the C interface to GEOS which is meant to be stable, hence use of boost::pool to manage memory of things I'm leaving GEOS with pointers to
- for some reason stackoverflow won't format this correctly, sorry!

```
    void my_geos_message_handler(const char *fmt, ...)
    {
        #ifdef DEBUG
            va_list args;
            va_start( args, fmt );
            vprintf( fmt, args );
            va_end( args );
            printf( "\n" );
        #endif
    }
    struct Point
    {
        double x,y;
        Point(double x,double y) : x(x),y(y) {}
    };
```

`typedef vector<Point> Cluster;
typedef vector<Cluster > ClusterList;

class ClusterFinder
{
public:
    ClusterFinder()
    {
        initGEOS(&my_geos_message_handler,&my_geos_message_handler);
        tree = GEOSSTRtree_create(10);
    }
    ~ClusterFinder()
    {
        GEOSSTRtree_destroy(tree);
        finishGEOS();
    }

    void add(const Point &p)
    {
        ClusterFinderNode *n = new (node_pool.malloc()) ClusterFinderNode(p);

        const double x = p.x;
        const double y = p.y;

        GEOSCoordSequence* coords = GEOSCoordSeq_create(1,2);
        GEOSCoordSeq_setX(coords,0,x);
        GEOSCoordSeq_setY(coords,0,y);
        GEOSGeometry * point = GEOSGeom_createPoint(coords); //point assumes ownership of coords
        GEOSSTRtree_insert(tree,point,(void*)n); //tree assumes ownership of point
    }

    ClusterList get_clusters(double tolerance)
    {
        ClusterFinderData data(tolerance,tree);
        GEOSSTRtree_iterate(tree,&try_to_find_cluster_starting_from_node,&data);
        return data.clusters;
    }


private:
    struct ClusterFinderNode
    {
        Point point;
        bool visited;
        ClusterFinderNode(const Point &p)
            :point(p),visited(false) {}
    };

    GEOSSTRtree* tree;
    boost::object_pool<ClusterFinderNode> node_pool;

    struct ClusterFinderData
    {
        ClusterList clusters;
        vector<ClusterFinderNode*> searchqueue;
        double tolerance;
        GEOSSTRtree *tree;
        ClusterFinderData(double t,GEOSSTRtree* tree):tolerance(t),tree(tree)
        {
            clusters.reserve(100);
            searchqueue.reserve(100);
        }
    };

    static void add_node_to_queue(void* vp_node,void* vp_clusterfinderdata)
    {
        ClusterFinderNode * const node = (ClusterFinderNode*) vp_node;
        ClusterFinderData * const cfd = (ClusterFinderData*) vp_clusterfinderdata;
        if (!node->visited)
        {
            cfd->searchqueue.push_back(node);
        }
    }

    static void check_node_for_neighbours(ClusterFinderNode *node,ClusterFinderData* cfd)
    {
        //mark visited and add to end of list
        node->visited = true;
        cfd->clusters.back().push_back(node->point);

        //add all neighbours within tolerance to search queue
        const double x = node->point.x;
        const double y = node->point.y;
        const double buffer = cfd->tolerance;

        GEOSCoordSequence* buffer_coords = GEOSCoordSeq_create(2,2);
        GEOSCoordSeq_setX(buffer_coords,0,x-buffer);
        GEOSCoordSeq_setY(buffer_coords,0,y-buffer);
        GEOSCoordSeq_setX(buffer_coords,1,x+buffer);
        GEOSCoordSeq_setY(buffer_coords,1,y+buffer);

        GEOSGeometry *line = GEOSGeom_createLineString(buffer_coords); //line takes ownership of buffer_coords
        GEOSGeometry *envelope = GEOSEnvelope(line);

        GEOSSTRtree_query(cfd->tree,envelope,&add_node_to_queue,(void*)cfd);

        GEOSGeom_destroy(line);
        GEOSGeom_destroy(envelope);
    }

    static void try_to_find_cluster_starting_from_node(void* vp_node,void* vp_clusterfinderdata)
    {
        ClusterFinderNode * const initial_node = (ClusterFinderNode*) vp_node;
        ClusterFinderData * const cfd = (ClusterFinderData*) vp_clusterfinderdata;

        if (initial_node->visited)
            return; //node was already discovered when starting from another node

        //push back new empty cluster vector
        cfd->clusters.push_back(Cluster());

        //initialize exploration queue
        assert(cfd->searchqueue.size()==0);
        cfd->searchqueue.push_back(initial_node);

        //explore node to fill cluster vector
        while (cfd->searchqueue.size()>0)
        {
            ClusterFinderNode* node_to_search_next = cfd->searchqueue.back();
            cfd->searchqueue.pop_back();
            check_node_for_neighbours(node_to_search_next,cfd);
        }

        //all found nodes will now be on end of cfd->clusters
        //remove cluster vector if no neighbours found
        Cluster &latest_cluster = cfd->clusters.back();
        if (latest_cluster.size() <= 1)
        {
            //should be a vector containing only the starting point
            //should never be size 0
            assert(latest_cluster.size()==1 && latest_cluster[0] == initial_node->point); 
            cfd->clusters.pop_back();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ClusterFinder cf;

    cf.add(Point(1,2));
    cf.add(Point(3,4));
    cf.add(Point(3.05,4));
    //etc

    ClusterList clusters = cf.get_clusters(0.1);
    return 0;
}`